# why scrollview with views is not able to scroll to till last?

Tags: ios, uiscrollview

I am adding UIScrollView in storyboard with all sides(trailing,leading,top,bottom) constraints. I have added a contentView inside a UIScrollView added constraints all sides(trailing,leading,top,bottom) and Equal width and Heights to SuperView(not scrollView) and changed height constraint priority to 250.

I have kept 3 views insdie content view for all views I have mentioned height and 3 sides(except bottom) but for last view I have kept all four sides and height.

But why i am not able to scroll till last view bottom.

[image: ScrollView Constraints[![][1]]][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/15WwI.jpg)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You give the contentView equal height constraint to main view ( Remove it )

[image]

While you should hook subviews of it so the scrollView will scroll according to the current content

Comment: But i have set priority as 250 and i tried your suggestion it wont work.

Answer (score 0):

Hey @santhosh I think you set a Equal height with `SuperView` is wrong 
 1. Remove ComentView Height constrains
 2. set  all(Three view) height and all constrains  `trailing,leading,top,bottom` 
  Automatically remove(scrollview) constrains error.
[image]